# Django url's apearence

Tags: python, django, oop, url, url-mapping

Consider the scenerio where, Iam creating a Django application where a user can SignUp and LogIn and do some stuff. So I created some functions like SignUp LogIn etc. in views.py file of the app. And I map it to corresponding urls in urls.py file. So while running locally, if I go to **localhost:8000/SignUp** the user will be taken to the SignUp page right! So my question is, how can I get the same thing done but the link be like **SignUp/localhost:8000** ? Or simply how can I bring the mapped urls to the beginning of my **localhost:8000** link? Is that possible in Django?

Sorry if my terminologies are bad... But I need to know this.
ThankYou for reading.

Answer (score 0):

in your url pattern you can made:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('your-app.urls', namespace='your-app-name')),
]
```

with a empty path.

In your urls.py from principal project folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('your-app.urls', namespace='your-app-name')),
]
```

And in your urls.py from app folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.YourAppView, name='your-view-app-name'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But how will this help my specific need!? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: with this you can use a empty url that you said here "simply how can I bring the mapped urls to the beginning of my localhost:8000 link?"

Comment: I made an exemple for you